# Trouble Getting Basic JSON Values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object similar to this one

```
{
 "x": [
       {
         "key": "value"
       },
       {
         "key2": "value2"
       }
      ]
}
```

And doing `console.log(x[0].key)` won't return 'value'. Instead I get an error saying that x is undefined.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Nit that isn't directly related to your question, but ought to be corrected: there should be a comma after the first closing `}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to start with whatever is holding the object.

E.g.

```js
var data = {
  "x": [
    {
      "key": "value"
    },
    {
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  ]
};
console.log(data.x[0].key);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return 'value'.

```
var x = {
         x: [{
               "key": "value" 
              },
              {
               "key2": "value2"
              }]
        };

console.log(x['x'][0].key);
```